# Hypothesis Testing via Chi Squared

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, exponential-distribution

I am having trouble understanding the application of chi square "power of the test" in context to hypothesis testing. The following is not homework, I'm simply providing an example to convey my confusion and obtain clarity from more experienced people throughout this forum.

Consider n=12 failures, total testing time is 76yrs, and then an exponential model assumed to evaluate a 90% two sided confidence interval for the mean time to failure of (4.17,10.98). I understand this procedure fine.

Continuing to assume exponential distribution for the time to failures moving forward.

Using this information, how can a chi squared test be used to test the hypothesis Ho: MTTF = 6 years, versus H1: MTTF < 6 years, at 5% level of significance.

The solution states that if the true MTTF is 5 years, then the power of the test is P(chi squared < 16.62).

Conceptually I am having a hard time understanding where this 16.62 number is coming from.

I have tried in Excel =CHISQ.INV(0.05,2*12)=13.848.

I have tried calculating the critical t-value as =(5-6)/(6/SQRT(12)) = -0.57735

And then calculating the left sided tail probability: =T.DIST(-0.57735,12-1,TRUE)=0.28766

And then calculating the corresponding chi squared value via =CHISQ.INV(0.28766,2*12)=19.72

Despite my trial-and-error, I still fail to evaluate 16.62 which is why I'm reaching out for assistance.

I suspect there is a gap in my knowledge which is limiting my ability to solve this problem. If anyone could please point me in the right direction it would be highly appreciated. Thank you.